# Stack overflow with Fibonacci function

Tags: f#, fibonacci

I'm still learning F#, so please be gentle with me! I tried to define a function to generate Fibonacci numbers like this...

```
let rec fib n =
  match n with
  | 0 -> 1
  | 1 -> 1
  | n -> fib(n-1) + (fib n-2)
```

However, whilst this gives the correct result for 0 and 1, it gives a stack overflow for 2. I know this isn't tail recursive, but for an input of 2, I wouldn't expect that to be an issue.

I thought pattern matching worked its way down, so with an input of 2, it would match the third pattern, giving a result of 1+1 (being the results of fib 0 and fib 1).

Why am I getting the SO?

Comment: Your parenthesis are wrong. Now it's equivalent to `| n -> fib(n-1) + ((fib n) - 2)`, which calls `fib n` until the stack overflows. It should be `| n -> fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)`. It's a simple typo, so I voted to close the question.

Comment: @JakubLortz Thanks for the explanation of my mistake. Not sure why you want to close the question though, I'm sure I'm not the first (or last) person who made this mistake. Might be useful for others.

Comment: A side note: make your function tail-recursive to avoid all kinds of stack overflow

Comment: @Mikhail Yes, I am aware of that thanks. I'm still learning F#, and was taking it one step at a time. I wanted a fib function that worked, then was going to modify it use tail recursion. Thanks for the reminder though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You statement:

```
| n -> fib(n-1) + (fib n-2)
```

Means:

```
| n -> fib(n-1) + fib(n)-2
```

If i have a call like this, it would work well with `fib(n-1)` since with each call value of n would be decremented by 1 while for `fib(n)` you would keep on calling  the same method with same value until you get stackoverflow exception. To avoid this, you need:

```
| n -> fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm quite new to F#, and am trying to drop brackets wherever they aren't needed, as much as anything to distinguish my F# from my C#. Looks like I was a bit too enthusiastic in this case!